# How do I hang up a tension curtain rod without it falling down?

Tags: curtain-rail

I bought [this MOYMO Room Divider Tension Curtain Rod, 122-150 inch](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0836G4C8L/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). No tools or drilling required! I tried 2 Methods, but both failed.

1. On ground, I insert curtain into curtain rod.

### Method 1

2. I pick a Spring Stop so that curtain rod matches [length of soffit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/197174/96467).

[image]

3. Then I go to window and lift it up. Because curtain rod matches length of soffit, I got to push it forcefully between soffit. Curtain rod hangs for an hour, but falls down!
4. I can't try Method 1 when it ruins my walls! When I push it forcefully between soffit, ends of curtain rod scrapes paint of walls.

### Method 2

5. I pick Spring Stop so that curtain rod just shorter than length of soffit. Then I walk to window with curtain rod NOT extended.
6. I hold up curtain rod at correct height. Then I pick the correct Spring Stop that most extends curtain rod between soffit.
7. But  no screw hole matches length of soffit. Curtain rod won't touch soffit on both ends! End of curtain rod has space between right side of soffit wall! Now what?

Comment: Why is it falling down?  It's either from lack of tension or lack of "friction" on the wall surface or a combination of both.  Can you add more tension?  Can you put something under the ends to adhere to the wall surface better?

Comment: "Can you add more tension?" See para. 7. "there's no screw hole that matches length of soffit". "Can you put something under the ends to adhere to the wall surface better?" I don't want add any thing to walls.

Comment: What do you mean by "screw hole"? I see none in your photos but I do see a spring and an adjustable spring stop.  Adjust it to provide more tension until it stays put.

Comment: I would cut a piece of rubber in the shape of the end cap; a piece of inner tube, or a "jar opener" gripper from the dollar store greatly increases holding capability while not altering the walls or rod; just place it between.

Comment: It's got a spring in it. You should adjust the length so that it's longer than the space you want it to go into, then compress the spring to make it shorter so that it fits in, then let go so that the spring presses then ends of the rod outwards to grip on the surface of the wall. So mostly like your "Method 1", but make sure that the rod is at least an inch or 2 longer than the soffit.

Comment: @jwh20 Thanks for teaching me! I meant "spring stop" by "screw hole". I edited post.